# Codeigniter 3 pass params to library construct, failed

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm passing an PDO instance to my library using this syntax

```
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db   = 'ci';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8';

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

    $params = array('pdo'=>$pdo);
    $this->load->library('phpauth/AuthConfig', $params);
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Argument 1 passed to AuthConfig::__construct() must be an instance of PDO, array given
```

I've searched the manual and other answers I don't see any wrong in my code, how it happens?

**By the way, the library I used needs a PDO instance, I have a few doubts here,**

1.Is my way of creating a PDO instance the proper way to do it in codeigniter 3?

2.Can I find this PDO instance after using $this->load->database() in my controller, I tried but I can not find it in controller instance

3.Library is using the raw PDO method, my last resort is to use CI3 built in query wrapper to re-style the library method, is this right?

Comment: Have you tried this `$this->load->library('phpauth/AuthConfig', $pdo);` and  no need of this line `$params = array('pdo'=>$pdo);`

Comment: @RejoanulAlam I tried and issued this AuthConfig::__construct() must be an instance of PDO, none given